# PHP Always not null

Tags: php

I have this piece of code in my cms:

```
<ul class="subsection_tabs" id="tab_group_one" style="clear:none;">
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('description')==NULL) { echo '<div id="trollweb_1"></div>'; } else echo('
    <li class="tab"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="trollweb_1" onClick="trollweb_tabs(1)" class="active"><h4>' . $this->__('Product Description'). '</h4></a></li> '); ?>
```

The problem is it always outputs the 'else'.  Even though I haven't filled in the description in the back end and it is blank.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `$this`? What does `$this->getChildHtml('description')` return? I doubt anyone can help you without knowing the answers to those questions.

Comment: Yes, make sure $this->getChildHtml('description') does not return NULL. Please give some more information.

Comment: $this->getChildHtml('description') returns a text area which can be completed in the backend of the cms (Magento).  I have left the text area blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe getChildHtml() always returns a string (not NULL). And maybe the string in your test environment only contains whitespaces.
In that case [trim()](http://docs.php.net/trim) removes them and you can simply check the length of the string

```
if ( 0<strlen(trim($this->getChildHtml('description'))) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to not test only for `NULL`, but also for empty strings, then you should do

```
$childHtml = $this->getChildHtml('description');
if (empty($childHtml))
```

instead.

**EDIT:** As VolkerK said, `empty('0')` returns false as well, so that solution depends on your requirements. As it looks, like you are looking for string solutions, this is viable option, as long as you do not have '0' as values.

Comment: empty only works for variables, not for return values of method calls:
http://php.net/empty